# UE4 BP can't make ball stick to player feet in socket

Tags: unreal-engine4, blueprint

As a GD I am trying to learn UE4 BP to make prototypes for my games ideas.

I am trying to attach a sphere base object to the player's when he enters collision with it, but it does not work. If I enable physics on the ball, it flies away, but if I don', it stays in place.

steps:

- I created a third person template project
- I created a base sphere object in it and scaled it to 0.3
- I enabled physics and actor overlap event on the ball
- I added a socket on the right foot of the skeletal mesh of the third person character
- I tried making the following blueprint but it does not work

[image]

I tried using the onactorhit too, placing self actor and other actor in object to try. For the onactorbeginoverlap I tried checking the "collision generate overlap event" on the third person character mesh and capsule, and now I am out of ideas and sample BP from the net.

Comment: Both actors need to have 'generate overlap events' enabled in order for `OnActorBeginOverlap` to be called

Comment: both have it, but the ball is still not picked up. is my BP linking correct ?

Comment: Are you also generating hit events? currently your blueprint flow assumes that `OnActorHit` will be called. If it is `OnActorBeginOverlap` that is being called, then the cast will always fail, because the `object` input node is attached to an output of a different event. Try instead attaching it to the overlapped actor pin of `OnActorBeginOverlap`.

Comment: I tried to rewire it but the behavior is the same

Comment: Is the event being called?

Comment: I tried adding logs or to print text when event should have started but nothing came up when I touched the ball

Comment: Ok great, so you know the problem is the collision settings and not the attachment. Show your collision settings for both components.

Comment: third person character is default except the generate hit events and generate overlap event which are all ticked. ball has both generate event boxes ticked, step up is set to no and collision preset is physics actor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-Check Your collision preset on the ball
2-Check the spelling of your socket name
3-Try to just make the ball a child of your mesh first then attach to component

Comment: 1 - collision preset is "physics actor", but the default "block all" gives the same behavior

Comment: 2 - spelling of the socket name is accurate

Comment: 3 - were you referring about BP snapping ? or permanent snapping ? because I need gameplay contextual snapping

Comment: if you want the physics to remain on the ball use a physics handle instead of attach to component

Comment: well I actually want to simulate a football, so I figured it did need physics but should become attached to the player when he picks it up until he releases it